# How to group 3 columns into a single one in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a table that has three columns: myColumn, myColumn2 and myColumn3. The three columns can have a different value but they are all the same type.

I need to do a join such that I merge all the items in the three columns and then group by

If I had a single column, it would be done like this:

```
select distinct (myColumn), COUNT(myColumn) as 'TotalF' 
from FormularioCorto 
where idEvento = @idEvento and myColumn <> ''
group by myColumn
```

The question is:
How do I do a TSQL statement that will allow for me to join the three columns and then group by?

Edit: here is the sample data
I have a table that has 3 columns with the same type

```
columna columnb columnc
a              a       b
b              a       b
c              c       d
```

I need to run a tsql that will merge the 3 columns and group by, to get a result like

```
newcolumn   count
a             3
b             3
c             2
d             1
```

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Comment: When you say you want to "merge" the three columns, what exactly does that mean? For example, do you want some new value which is a combination of all three? Or do you want the first column that isn't NULL? Or something else?

Comment: It is not very clear what you want. Why don't you add a data sample and the expected result based on that sample to your question?

Comment: Combining three queries (one for each column) using UNION ALL as shown in my answer works. Did you try it?

Comment: Thanks for your help Brian. You helped me finish the stored proc I needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you mean concatenate rather than JOIN. JOIN has a very [specific meaning](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) with SQL. Use the [+ operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177561.aspx) to concatenate string fields.

Answer (score 5):

It is hard to tell without some sample data and desired output but a guess would be something like:

```
SELECT MyCol as MyColumn, Count(*) as 'TotalF'
FROM 
(
  SELECT myColumn MyCol from FormularioCorto 
  WHERE idEvento = @idEvento AND myColumn <> ''
  UNION ALL
  SELECT myColumn2 MyCol from FormularioCorto 
  WHERE idEvento = @idEvento AND myColumn2 <> ''
  UNION ALL
  SELECT myColumn3 MyCol from FormularioCorto 
  WHERE idEvento = @idEvento) AND myColumn3 <> ''
) A
GROUP BY MyCol;
```

Or for just the example data and result:

```
SELECT NewColumn, Count(*) as Count FROM
(
  SELECT columna as NewColumn FROM SomeTable
  UNION ALL
  SELECT columnb as NewColumn FROM SomeTable
  UNION ALL
  SELECT columnc as NewColumn FROM SomeTable
) A
Group by NewColumn
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CONCAT(`myColumn`, `myColumn2`, `myColumn3`) as joinedField
```

The CONCAT() function concatenates fields and strings.

Info:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat

*Note: You should reconsider your structure though, as this will prove to be painfully slow as you add more records.*

Comment: The question concerns SQL-Server. 'CONCAT' is not a recognized built-in function name.

Comment: Note that the original question specifically asked for a TSQL solution. The CONCAT function doesn't exist in TSQL / SQL Server. The appropriate way to concatenate strings in TSQL is using the + operator.

Answer (score 0):

```
select cast(myColumn as nvarchar) + CAST(COUNT(myColumn)as nvarchar) as 'TotalF' 
from FormularioCorto 
where idEvento = @idEvento and myColumn <> ''
group by myColumn
```

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question right, then you simply want 2 columns (one identifying the id you are counting and one giving the count for the identifier. If this is correct, simply use your existing query for each column and union the results.

For example;

```
SELECT myColumn AS Id, COUNT(myColumn) AS IdCount
FROM FormularioCorto
where idEvento = @idEvento and myColumn <> ''
GROUP BY myColumn 
UNION
SELECT myColumn2 AS Id, COUNT(myColumn2) AS IdCount
FROM FormularioCorto
where idEvento = @idEvento and myColumn2 <> ''
GROUP BY myColumn2
```

etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT myColumn1 + myColumn2 + myColumn3 AS AllThreeFields 
FROM   FormularioCorto 
WHERE  1=1
GROUP BY myColumn1 + myColumn2 + myColumn3
```

It won't be fast but it should work.  If you need to delimit the data in the columns with other characters you can try this:

```
SELECT myColumn1 + ' ' + myColumn2 + ' ' + myColumn3 AS AllThreeFields 
FROM   FormularioCorto 
WHERE  1=1
GROUP BY myColumn1 + myColumn2 + myColumn3
```

If the column types are not the same (you said they were), you will need to cast them to a similar type.